# Spelling out words using Android voice typing

Tags: google-maps-navigation, voice

My work days are mostly spent on the road visiting clients, so Google Maps is an app that I constantly use.  I am able to perform most actions in Maps using voice typing with minimal manual interaction, but there is one thing I just can't get voice typing to do.

Addresses sometimes have English words, like "3846 Beaver Hall Hill".  But some addresses have non-English words like "7125 Papineau Avenue".  Is there a way to spell out words in voice typing?  There could be keywords that begin and end spell-mode.
Ex:  To get '7125 Papineau Avenue', I would say "seventy-one twenty-five start-spell p a p i n e a u end-spell Avenue".  This would enable Maps users to enter any addresse without ever having to use the keyboard.  This is important because fines are hefty for using your phone while driving.  (I have never gotten one, but that's besides the point :)

As it stands, when I try to spell things out, this is what I get:  I say "seventy-one twenty-five p a p i n e a u Avenue" and I get '7125 P A P I N E A U Avenue'.  Wouldn't be a need for keywords if Google didn't put spaces between the letters.  Furthermore, if I say "7125 p a p i n e a u Avenue", I get '7 1 2 5 P A P I N E A U Avenue' - even worse!

Does anyone know how to do this?
Many thanks!